# Will Go leak memory if a goroutine is trying to send a message on a thread that no one is listening on?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

### Synopsis

I have a timer utility that I wrote—its exact purpose isn't important, but that's the motivating context—which spawns one process to sleep for a certain amount of time, and another process to listen on a channel to know when to run a function.

Here's the catch: I need to be able to restart that timer. I've decided to make it so that I can swap out which channel the function-running process is listening on, effectively making it so that it waits for a *different* process to send a message.

### Code

Here's the code I've written:

```golang
type Timer struct {
    mu    sync.Mutex
    Alarm func() // Function to run on timeout

    lastInterval time.Duration   // Last time used (for "reset")
    lastWakeCh   chan int        // Where is the alarm listening?
    alarmUpdate  chan (chan int) // Update what channel the alarm runs on
}

func (t *Timer) start(timeout time.Duration) {
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()

    t.lastInterval = timeout
    t.lastWakeCh = make(chan int)
    t.alarmUpdate = make(chan (chan int))

    go sleepAndNotify(timeout, t.lastWakeCh)
    go alarmThread(t.alarmUpdate, t.Alarm)
    t.alarmUpdate <- t.lastWakeCh
}

func (t *Timer) restart() {
    t.mu.Lock()
    defer t.mu.Unlock()

    t.lastWakeCh = make(chan int)
    t.alarmUpdate <- t.lastWakeCh
    go sleepAndNotify(t.lastInterval, t.lastWakeCh)
}

func sleepAndNotify(timeout time.Duration, ch chan int) {
    time.Sleep(timeout)
    ch <- 1
}

func alarmThread(chUpdate chan (chan int), alarm func()) {
    ch := <-chUpdate

    for {
        select {
        case newCh := <-chUpdate:
            ch = newCh
        case <-ch:
            go alarm()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```golang
t1 := Timer{Alarm: func() { ... }}
t1.start(100 * time.Millisecond)
// some time passes
t1.restart()
```

Note that every time `restart` is called, a new goroutine running `sleepAndNotify` will be created, and will block while trying to send a message down the wake channel `ch`.

Will this cause a memory/process leak? Or is Go smart enough to see that there are no more references to this channel (or something like that) and so no other process could possible read from this, and just abort that goroutine?

If that is not the case, is there a cheap and easy fix for this?

Comment: The goroutine will remain in memory forever. Why not just use `time.Timer` which has a `Timer.Reset()` method?

Comment: @icza Thank you for the answer! Do you happen to have a source? As for `timer.Timer`, the lab I'm working on expressly recommended against using that, otherwise I probably would have reached for that first. :) I know the specific use case here is a little odd—I'm more curious about the concept of what happens with forever blocked threads than how to build a timer.

Comment: See [Dave Cheney: Never start a goroutine without knowing how it will stop](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/12/22/never-start-a-goroutine-without-knowing-how-it-will-stop)